# linkedin integration with cocoa app OS X. i need to send invitiations to linkedin contacts from my cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

linkedin integration with cocoa app OS X. i need to send invitiations to linkedin contacts from my cocoa app.please give detail explanation and sample codes as i am new biee to cocoa programming
i am using this project to try something atleast...https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client

but not able to do kindly please help..

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. What sort of integration are you looking for? Where are you running into trouble? What isn't working for you?

Comment: i need to integrate linkedin with cocoa app(OSX). i need to send inviations to linkedin contacts from my app.how to do it? please help me